# How to stop an Oozie coordinator?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I ran an Oozie coordinator which runs a workflow every hour. I don't have its id and when I run the command `oozie jobs -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie` it only shows me the workflow jobs and there is no coordinator. I would like to stop this coordinator from further processing, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

First an advice in order to avoid to define the oozie URL in each command

```
export OOZIE_URL=http://localhost:11000/oozie
```

You can list running coordinators

```
oozie jobs -jobtype coordinator -filter status=RUNNING
```

This will return a list displaying the coordinator ID `<coord_id>` in the first column.

*Note that you must have appropriate rights to run the following commands.*

Then you can suspend the coordinator

```
oozie job -suspend `<coord_id>`
```

And resume it.

```
oozie job -resume <coord_id>
```

But often you have to kill it

```
oozie job -kill <coord_id>
```

and redeploy it...

```
oozie job -config job.properties -run
```

Comment: Is the double export intentional?

Answer (score 2):

For coordinator jobs, try this

```
oozie jobs -jobtype coordinator -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie
```

Answer (score 0):

```
su - {username} -c 'oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -kill {Workflow External Id or coordinator's external Id}'
```

To execute this command you need to login to your oozie cluster or you can also run from local machine for that you need to replace localhost to box address where oozie is running..
Thanks